# password protected Base64 string convert into pdf file without password

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Encrypted PDF File and i have convert encypted PDF file To Base64 string. I want Base64 string convert into PDF File (Means PDF file will write without password). PDF File should open.

Encrypted Base64  string is perfectly convert into pdf file but when i am trying to open the pdf file it is asking password.

I want when file is convert into Encryted base64 to PDF File then it should open without password .File is saving on my folder.

```
How i can do it. with asp.net with c#.
```

Comment: This is a terrible question. Please read [ask].

Comment: If you want a tip though: don't password protect the PDF file before you base64 encode its binary data, then you won't have this problem.

Comment: _”...Means PDF file will write without password...”_ - says who?

Answer (score 1):

Can’t be done.

Otherwise the mere act of emailing a password protected PDF removes the protection and I’m pretty sure the payslips I get are protected.

Comment: Ms print to pdf solves this issue but most web servers disable print spooling. How does PrintDocument() work because if we could understand that then we could figure this out!